# Loading files on client-side react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good afternoon,
I am trying to create a React (static) application, made of only on client-side. I do not need server.
On client-side there are several images.. I would like to find a way in which the admin of the application is able to load images and to put them into public/img folder of react application.
Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `assets` folder inside `src`. That will be the folder where you store the images. See [React: Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

```
/* Component.js */
import React from 'react';
import image from 'PathToAssetsFolder/img.png'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image

console.log(image); // PathToAssetsFolder/img.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={image} alt="Image" />;
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: I probably explained the problem wrongly. I know how to load an image inside a react application. 
The thing that I do not know is how to upload an external image at runtime and put them into public/images (for example through e sort of form). 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean uploading the images via an input file?

Comment: yep, I mean uploading via an input file, without using a server, just on client-side.

Comment: I might be wrong, but client side javascript doesn't allow to read/write files. You'd need a server.